# Last failed command in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, environment-variables

The `$?` variable holds the exit status of last run command. Is there a variable that holds last run command itself?

Comment: Related question on Stack Overflow: [BASH: echoing the last command run](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6109225)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `fc` to get the previous command line. It is normally used to edit the previous command line in your favourite editor, but it has a "list" mode, too:

`last_command="$(fc -nl -1)"`

Comment: this sadly doesn't work well quite how I expected if there are large case statements in use or functions in use... :(    I ended up using `caller` and the bash arrays `BASH_LINENO`, `BASH_SOURCE`, and `FUNCNAME` to do a kind of stack trace.

Comment: Works in interactive shell but not well in script. The "DEBUG trap" approach below is better

Answer (score 7):

*If* the last command was executed without arguments, it'll be saved in the `$_` variable. This normally contains the *last argument* of previous command - so if there were no arguments, the value of `$_` is the last command itself.

Another option is to learn the details of last *background* command. As l0b0 wrote, `$!` holds its PID - so you can parse the output of `ps $!` (possibly with additional formating options to `ps`).

Answer (score 7):

The [`DEBUG` trap](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap-125) lets you execute a command right before any simple command execution. A string version of the command to execute (with words separated by spaces) is available in the [`BASH_COMMAND`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-BASH_005fCOMMAND-169) variable.

```
trap 'previous_command=$this_command; this_command=$BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
…
echo "last command is $previous_command"
```

Note that `previous_command` will change every time you run a command, so save it to a variable in order to use it. If you want to know the previous command's return status as well, save both in a single command.

```
cmd=$previous_command ret=$?
if [ $ret -ne 0 ]; then echo "$cmd failed with error code $ret"; fi
```

If you only want to abort on a failed commands, use [`set -e`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set-149) to make your script exit on the first failed command. You can display the last command from the [`EXIT` trap](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-trap-125).

```
set -e
trap 'echo "exit $? due to $previous_command"' EXIT
```

An alternate approach that might work for some uses is to use [`set -x`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-set-149) to print a trace of the script's execution and examine the last few lines of the trace.

Comment: If you only want to trigger the `trap` when an error occured (the case for `set -e`), you can use the signal (last argument) `ERR` instead of `EXIT` and get rid if the `if`.

Answer (score 3):

[No, but](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html) you can get it during execution to store for other commands:

- `$0`: Path of the current shell script.
- `$FUNCNAME`: "Name of the current function."
- `"$@"`: All the parameters of the current command, quoted separately.
- `$!`: "PID (process ID) of last job run in background."
- `$$`: "Process ID (PID) of the script itself."

The full command of the current *script* should therefore be `"$0" "$@"`. If it's a function it should be `"$FUNCNAME" "$@"`. You might want to store that in an array for future processing. For example, store this in `test.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo()
{
    declare -a command=("$0")
    for param in "$@"
    do
        command+=("$(printf %q "$param")")
    done
    echo "${command[@]}"
}
foo "$@"
```

When running `./test.sh "first argument" "second argument"`, it should return:

```
./test.sh first\ argument second\ argument
```

Which are equivalent calls.

Comment: In bash there is a `BASH_COMMAND` variable, but do not seems to be useful in any way, apart from use in traps.

Comment: Thanks for your input. What about if I run `some-command` in a shell script, and it fails. I'll have non-zero status in `$?`, will "no" still hold for the existence of variable holding `some-command`?

Comment: As far as I know, the sole fact that a command failed does not change the set of information your shell stores about it. So I'd say *Yes, "no"*.

Answer (score 1):

I find it essential to find the last failed command when having `set -e` and `set -o pipefail` options, as otherwise bash simply aborts with no feedback on why, so this is what I found working well:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -eu
set -o pipefail

cur_command=
first_err_command=
first_err_lineno=
# This trap is executed in exactly the same conditions in which the `set -e` results in an exit.
trap 'cur_command=$BASH_COMMAND;
      if [[ -z "$first_err_command" ]]; then
          first_err_command=$cur_command;
          first_err_lineno=$LINENO;
      fi' ERR
trap 'if [[ ! -z "$first_err_command" ]]; then
          echo "ERROR: Aborting at line: $first_err_lineno on command: $first_err_command";
      fi' EXIT

echo "The following command causes bash to abort, but it should also result in a nice message"
false
echo "This message is not expected"
```

If you run the above, you will end up seeing the below below sort of output:

```
The following command causes bash to abort, but it should also result in a nice message
ERROR: Aborting at line: 22 on command: false
```

The line number may not always be accurate, but it should give you something close enough to be useful.